# Remove Query String Parameters

Tags: azure-api-management, url-masking

> Is there any way to remove query string parameters from url in azure
>   api management?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can do this by setting the URL template on the operation screen in the publisher portal. Just include the parameters you wish to forward on to your backend, the others will not be.

Alternatively, you can use the [set-query-parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894083.aspx#SetQueryStringParameter) policy, which gives you full control of the parameters you are using.

Comment: Using set-query-parameters in policy did the trick thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
<rewrite-uri template="your/template" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
```