# Policy to remove query parameter from URL in APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an API in APIM. When my API is called, I want to remove one of the query parameters from the URL ("ax-ky" in the code) and keep the rest (Page). I was thinking policies in APIM would help me remove "ax-ky". I've tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254160/how-to-specify-rewrite-url-for-query-string-parameters-in-azure-api-management?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048329/remove-query-string-parameters) but they have not been working with my API. After implementing the new inbound policy below, I get 500 status code with the message "Internal server error".

Currently my code is in the "Inbound" policy, shown below:

```html
        <set-query-parameter name="ax-ky" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.Product.Name)</value>
        </set-query-parameter>
        <rewrite-uri template="_/_?Page={Page}" />
```

**Edit:** Adding screenshot of Trace "set-query-parameter" --> Query parameter is removed in set-query-parameter but not when the URL is returned to the user.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have tried to reproduce the issue at my environment and got the expected result**

Here I am using Echo API wherein I am removing param1 from Get resource operation and keeping the rest URL as it is by using the below policy

```
<inbound>
<base />
<set-query-parameter  name="param1"  exists-action="delete"  />
</inbound>
```

**`Test Result`**

[image]

**Requested URL is**

[image]

**Response**

[image]

**In Trace, I could see below changes in the Request URL**

[image]

Try changing **`exists-action="override"`** to **`exists-action="delete"`** in your policy, you will get the result too.

Comment: Hi @Ikhtesam Afrin, I did exactly what you did and it still does not change the URL in my case. In this situation "ax-ky" is the variable that is the subscription key the user passes, could that be the reason why it is not deleting?

Comment: Can you share the trace screenshot please like the way I have shared for set query parameter?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my initial post. The query parameters are removed in set-query-parameters but not when I access the API through my browser. The parameter is still visible in the URL.

Comment: set-query-parameters removes the query parameter from the request URL and send the modified URL to backend. You can see the detailed information in Trace.

Comment: Gotcha, it makes sense. Is there a way to make this backend URL the current URL that the browser shows?

Comment: Not sure if this is even feasible to achieve as we are sending the current modified URL to backend only. I am aware of set-backend-service policy but it sets the backend url and even rewrite-url change the current url and send it to backend.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you. I'll still be looking into if it is possible.